# Need help to improve my CRUD operation code with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I recently wrote code to perform a crud operation in hibernate java.

If I need to perform a delete operation, I show the user the data table and delete button with every entry. When the user presses that button the corresponding entry gets deleted from the table and database. I do it by sending a uniqueID in the url but if the user changes the id using inspect element then the wrong entry gets deleted every time.

So I need help to overcome this problem.

[image: Image of form and inspect screen]

Comment: are you using jsp , webservices , ... ? please more details

Comment: Please remember  to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you are posting a question. At the moment we have no idea how you have implemented your Java code and your webpage data and cannot suggest how to prevent this without it.

Answer (score 0):

you are talking about security , in this case you need to limit permissions for every user
using sessions (jsp) or Auth2.0 .. on webservices

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what kind of ORM framework you use (hibernate or other).

Generally there is no common strategy to solve your problem. It is very difficult problem and the solution strongly depends on multiple factors (size of application, architecture, etc.).

You should investigate security of application at all. You should think about [authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) and [authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) of users who use your application.

First of all to prevent execution of not desirable operation I would suggest you read about [CRSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). It doesn't connect directly to your issue, but it is the same problem  in wider manner.

If you write this code for educational purposes, you can implement simple authorization component, which will help to define possibility of doing operation before performing. For instance, in this component you can get all employee details which could be deleted for authenticated user and provide authority to perform this operation. It can get you overview of an security approach.